# Show Gtk file dialog in Qt apps in LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, qt, lxde

I'm on Lubuntu Xenial, using LXDE. The Qt applications don't show the native dialog, instead they show some Qt default style. How can I fix that?

Native: [image]
Qt: [image]

Comment: Could you advise the version of Qt being used?

Comment: The version is Qt 5.5.1

Comment: Could you `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and then launch the application and provide the output it generates?

Comment: Done - https://pastebin.com/BY3zhjPe. The problem happens for Qt5 applications, but not for Qt4 applications - they work fine in this regard.

Comment: Have you built Qt yourself?

Comment: No, it's what comes with the system (apt-get I assume).

Comment: Have you tried `export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` before launching the application?